# NavigatorIOS React native translucent

Tags: react-native, routes, react-native-ios, navigator-ios

I'm using a NavigatorIOS for the routing of my app. I would like to display just the back button without any title or bar even translucent. 
Is it possible ? 
Or I must use another module ? 
Currently, I have this :

```
 <NavigatorIOS
    ref='nav'
    tintColor="white"
    style={{flex: 1}}
    initialRoute={{
      title: 'Splash',
      navigationBarHidden: true,
      component: SplashScene
    }}/>
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

Margot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass translucent prop to NavigatorIOS's route, like so:

```
<NavigatorIOS
    ref='nav'
    tintColor="white"
    style={{flex: 1}}
    initialRoute={{
        title: 'Splash',
        navigationBarHidden: true,
        translucent: true,
        component: SplashScene
    }}
/>
```